# Firebase convert string to timestamp

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

I want to store the data in firebase but from client side I received eventData.startdate as string of `startDate : '2019-12-23T09:25:59.219Z'`. I want to save it as timestamp in firebase so I am required to convert it but I tried to change it by doing `startDate : eventData.startDate.toDate()` and receive error of `.toDate()` not a function.

```
batch.set(eventRef, {
    startDate: eventData.startDate ? eventData.startDate : '',
});
```

Comment: You will need a library such as momentjs to parse that string and convert it into a Date object which you can pass to Firestore directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase uses the format you already have for [Timestamps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp). If you want to convert that to a unix timestamp in milliseconds, you can do this:

```
batch.set(eventRef, {
    startDate: eventData.startDate ? new Date(eventData.startDate).valueOf() : '',
});
```

```js
const startDate = '2019-12-23T09:25:59.219Z';
console.log(new Date(startDate).valueOf());
```